# Props data appears undefined when trying to render screen for testing

Tags: javascript, react-native, unit-testing, jestjs

I'm doing jest testing for my react-native app and I want to test that my Game Screen renders correctly. I wrote the following test below to pass the required params to the Game Screen.

```
  it("renders correctly", () => {
    const mockedParams = {
      route: { params: { words: ["superior", "baikal"], stage: 0 } },
      navigation: ''
    };

    const gameScreen = renderer.create(<GameScreen {...mockedParams} />).toJSON();

    expect(gameScreen).toBeTruthy();
  });
```

Game Screen

```
const Game = ({ route, navigation }) => {
  const {words, stage} = route.params;
  const [lives, setLives] = useState(3);
  const [points, setPoints] = useState(0);
  const [level, setLevel] = useState(0);
  const [letters, setLetters] = useState(words[level].word.split(""));
  const [curLetter, setCurLetter] = useState(0);
  const [showPopup, setShowPopup] = useState(false);
  const [rows, setRows] = useState(
    new Array(1).fill(new Array(letters.length).fill(""))
  );
```

However when I run the test, I get the following error:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'split' of undefined

It seems like the words prop is undefined when it gets passed to the Game Screen even though I have defined values for it in my test file. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Params: `{ words: ["superior", "baikal"], ...}`

You're using: `words[level].word.split("")`

So you don't have a `words[level].word`.

You can tell that params are defined because it gets to `word` instead of `words` before there's an error. You could confirm this by logging out your params at the top of your component, but that part looks fine.

Your component is expecting something like `{ words: [{ word: "superior" }, ...}`, so either pass it that way, or access the current params with `words[level].split`.